# ngx-chips formgroup data dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm on initial stage of learning Angular and using version 6 to develop an application. I have created an example on StackBiz in which want to display data in  dynamically which will be populated from an list. I have already created this using normal  but this time need to use this in FormGroup for which not getting any example online.

[Please find below the link of example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kikbzg?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Please help me to achieve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error is coming on example do not know why it is coming.. "ERROR
Error: this._onTouchedCallback is not a function"

Comment: Please provide more details. Your stackblitz seems to work fine. What exactly do you want to achieve? What isn't working?

Comment: i have just updated my fiddle check that now, problem is my tag input data is coming same when i click on add new rule.

Comment: What should happen when you click on 'add new rule'?

Comment: it should give me empty chips where i can enter new values which should not be same like earlier values

Comment: When I click on `add new rule` a new company is created with empty fields for project, roles and countries. Seems to work fine. Is this what you want? I still don't understand the problem you have.

Comment: Please check this URL that stackblitz was having some issue it was not reflecting code updates after saving .....https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6b53dv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You have to remove `[(ngModel)]` from all of your `tag-input` elements. If you're using reactive forms you can't use `ngModel` at the same time. There is also a warning about this on the console.